# Android Refresh Listview issue.

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am having an issue with a listview refresh, I have a refresh function that works on load and when I click a button tied to it. What it will not do is refresh after I add info to the SQLite database and call the refresh function.

```
    //Add item to order Table.
    public void addItemToOrder()
{
    itemNumberValue = qoItemNumber.getText().toString();
    orderQtyValue = qoOrderQty.getText().toString();
    itemDescValue = qoItemDesc.getText().toString();


    Intent searchItem = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),inputOrder.class);

    searchItem.putExtra("itemnumb", itemNumberValue);
    searchItem.putExtra("orderqty", orderQtyValue);
    searchItem.putExtra("qoitemdesc", itemDescValue);

    startActivity(searchItem);
    fillData();

}

    //Load item table to listview
    public void fillData() {
        // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
        mNotesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllOrders();
        startManagingCursor(mNotesCursor);



        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{HDWDBHelper.KEY_ITEMNUM, HDWDBHelper.KEY_DESC, HDWDBHelper.KEY_QTY};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        //int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvItemNum, R.id.tvItemDesc, R.id.tvQty};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlist, mNotesCursor, from, to);


        notes.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setListAdapter(notes);
        notes.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.v("fillData", "In fillData");
    }
```

When I call fillData() at onCreate() or on button click, it works but when I call it in the addItemToOrder() function, nothing happens. The listview still shows previous items listed until I click the refresh button then it shows the new item added.

Comment: Because you are going to InputOrder.class before filling data.

Comment: I am adding the data then filling it to display.

Comment: my question is why have you used startactivity? What do you want to do by starting another activity? I asking this becasuse you are adding your data in current Activity, then starting a new Activity i.e inputOrder class & then filling data in again current activity. So what is your exact flow?

Comment: The inputOrder class opens the DB and inserts data from the text fields in the current activity. Then I need to run the filldata to re-display the list with all the data that is now in the order table. IS there a better way to handle this, maybe just add the inputorder functions in the current activity and just call them local?

Comment: Definitely you have to Make a local method of Inputorder class.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar when I created a local method, it works fine.

Comment: You can upvote my comment if you like.